# TB16 on XPS 15 9550 Running Ubuntu

Tags: thunderbolt

I have a TB16 dock and a XPS 15 9550 dual booting Windows and Ubuntu.

Everything about the TB16 dock when booting into Windows is just fine, but everytime I boot into Ubuntu, only the display works. Every port that are not the display ports on the TB16 are not working. I've already tried disabling the security on thunderbolt on the latest BIOS. I've also tried updating my Ubuntu to 17.04 and a kernel of 4.11.7. Nothing seems to work and I'm at a bit of a dead end now. Any ideas?

Comment: See this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/934450/turn-off-wifi-when-connected-to-thunderbolt-dock) where the Dell Thunderbolt 3 docking station is working, only it's complicated by WiFi status.

Answer (score 1):

In the BIOS, disable thunderbolt security in "system configuration" - "Usb". This should fix your issues. After doing that, my (almost identical) setup works fine.